# How do I animate two objects together with different textures

Tags: animation, texturing, groups

I have got an object (a mouse cursor) and I want to animate it.
But, since my scene is pretty dark, I would like to add a small ball of light, which would also give the cursor a nice sci-fi effect.

The thing is, how can I link to object and animated them as one, without transferring the texture from one to another.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, you can have several textures in one object, so you could join your cursor and your light ball and they would keep their own textures... but anyway, you could simply parent your light ball to your cursor so it follows its animation

Comment: You could parent the light to the pointer object? Or use a transform constraint on the light to follow the changes like position of the pointer.

Comment: Thank you folks, I will try that. I am pretty new to Blender & 3D.

Comment: You guys are genious! I've been learning 3D since... Monday and getting better everyday (actually spending 10-12 hours on blender per day) so I got a lot to learn but the community is really awesome and of great help! Thank you folks!